# Как создать шаблон Web-application ASP.NET на macOS?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net, macos, mac

У меня macOS, на которую установлен Visual Studio. Как именно создать проект с шаблоном Web-application ASP.NET?
Если я выбираю данный пункт
[image: новый проект Visual Studio]
То у меня пустая панель элементов. Где мне взять элементы button, textbox, dropdownlist, checkbox, label?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]